# Is it possible to use both fglrx and Intel graphic drivers simultaneously?

Tags: drivers, intel, fglrx

I have just installed Ubuntu and I'm using the following setup:

```
AMD R9 270 (2 monitors)
Intel HD 2500 (1 monitor)
```

With the default configuration after installing Ubuntu (radeon driver for the R9 270) it just works but I tried to install the proprietary drivers of AMD and the third monitor stopped working. I would like to know if its possible to use both fglrx and the Intel driver at the same time (not just switching between them).

Here is a screenshot of the default configuration with the radeon driver.
[image]

I tried to follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/117239/how-can-i-get-multiple-video-cards-to-work-on-linux). I wrote [this xorg.conf file](http://pastebin.com/t7kGXQ7v).

As it is, the AMD GPU works, but if I uncomment the HD2500 lines, it throws an error and the desktop environment doesn't boot. ([/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/MV64Kts8))

I've noticed that if I change the Intel device driver from "intel" to anything else, it boots and the monitor displays [the ubuntu plymouth theme](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vs0vHKOfLFA/UIJIBuUQEnI/AAAAAAAABjs/sNxZ9gLwj58/s510/1350715389451.png) loading instead of just black. (the monitors connected to the AMD card work just fine).

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Answered here https://superuser.com/questions/462761/amd-gpu-but-display-on-intel-integrated-graphics